# Running multiple processes performing long tasks in the background of Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron, service-worker

I have an Electron app.

It is a Multi-Login browser that allows you to create multiple separate browsing sessions, each one with its own set of tabs.

See the demo below.

I need to run one "background" process for each session, to perform long tasks such as running long API calls, as well as communicating with each one of the open visible tabs on the same session.

It should also have access the the DOM.

How can I accomplish that?
Is it possible to have an additional renderer running in the background for each one of the sessions, and have them keep running in the background while the user switched to other sessions?

[image]